# Visual Studio Class View Vs Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio

I have a simple question - are Class View and Object Browser in Visual Studio one and the same? If so why have both of them? Thanks!

Comment: No; They are not the same thing

Comment: What's the difference then? Looks identical at first glance...

Comment: I don’t have Visual Studio in front of me so I can’t write a full answer